# Running elevated applications on user login with UAC?

Tags: c#, uac, startup

I need to start a program every time the user logs in, but I cannot do this without being met by a UAC dialog asking for permissions for that application. Is there any way to have an application start up on user login without the user having to answer the UAC prompt? I was thinking about running a service, but this would be a last resort. I saw something about an Application Compatibility Toolkit to disable UAC for certain applications, but I feel this is too big of a hassle - even services would be easier to program. I was just wondering if there is an even easier solution I am missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're asking for a security hole as a feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not an easier answer.  You should use a service in this situation.  Not at all difficult.

Comment: Fully agree, if there was an easy answer, every program would use it and bypass UAC.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer here has been picked but there is another solution. You can add a manifest as an embedded resource and set the `requestedExecutionLevel` to `asInvoker`. This is assuming that your application is not doing anything that a low level user could not do with having to elevate privileges. It should also be noted that your code must be signed.

For more:

- [Create and Embed an Application
  Manifest with Your Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx)
- [CAS and How to properly elevate with
  Vista UAC](http://robertseder.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!587F478B9240C01E!499.entry)

Comment: Good point. We don't know why the app is elevating. If it's accidental, a manifest requesting "asInvoker" would put a stop to it. If it needs to elevate I agree a service is the way to go, assuming it doesn't communicate with the logged-in user.